# How to use if condition in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have below values in values.yaml

```
  pg_hba:
    - hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - host    all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

The reqiurement is  to check the `hostssl` line exists , if yes it should go into the if loop and do something.

i tried to use `{{ if has "hostssl" .Values.pg_hba }}`
but it seraches only for the exact string "hostssll" and not the entire line.

Please help on how i can check for the entrire line in if condition.

Comment: What you mean by "hostssl line exists"? Do you want to check if line contains `hostssl`?

Comment: Hi Grigoriy,
ii want to check if the "hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"   contains /exits in if condition
Please note the values after hostall  may chnage as per the requirement.

Answer (score 30):

I have not fully understood your question, so here are 3 options.

To check if two string are equal, Go has built in template function [`eq`](https://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Functions), here is use example:

```
{{ if eq "line" "line" }}
> true
```

If you want to check if line **contains** `hostssl` string. Helm has [`sprig`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig) as it's dependency -- it's module that provides additional template functions. One of these functions is `contains`, that checks if string is contained inside another:

```
{{ if contains "cat" "catch" }}
> true
```

If you want to check, if string has `hostssl` precisely at it's start you can use another function, provided by `sprig` -- `hasPrefix`:

```
{{ if hasPrefix "cat" "catch" }}
> true
```

[Here is a list of all string functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) that `sprig` offers. If none of above options does satisfy your requirement, you can use regex function for matching.

Comment: Below is the content in values.yaml ,
spec:
  patroni:
    pg_hba:
    - hostssl all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - host    all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5


i tried as below , 
{{ if hasPrefix "hostssl" .Values.spec.patroni.pg_hba }

But i see  below error:

 template: postgres-operator-cluster/templates/pkicertificate.yaml:1:33: executing "postgres-operator-cluster/templates/pkicertificate.yaml" at <.Values.spec.patroni.pg_hba>: wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {}

Comment: @NeelamSharma `.Values.spec.patroni.pg_hba` is array. You need to iterate over it and apply `hasPrefix` to each entry. Also, you need to convert interface to string(or quote values in `values.yaml`). There's plenty of answers on how you can do that on SO. Use search

Comment: I have defined below function to iterate over the range and use if condition:

{{- define "sslmode" }}
{{- range $k, $v := $.Values.spec.patroni }}
{{ index $k | trim | -}}:
{{ if hasPrefix "hostssl" $k }}
{{- $v | toYaml | trimSuffix "\n"| nindent 2 -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

But the O/P returned is as :
  pg_hba:

Please let me know what I'm missing

Comment: You iterate over `Values.spec.patroni`, but need to iterate over `Values.spec.patroni.pg_hba`

Comment: i tried tht option too but it gives the same error as:

executing "postgres-operator-cluster/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "sslmode" .>: error calling include: template: postgres-operator-cluster/templates/_helpers.tpl:61:14: executing "sslmode" at <trim>: wrong type for value; expected string; got int

Comment: @NeelamSharma `{{ index $k | trim | -}}` -- you're trimming index, not value. Instead try `{{ index $v | trim | -}}`. But still, it probably won't work, because you have interface values, so, first you need to convert them to string.

Answer (score 2):

I had a use case where I need to write my yaml's in such a way that, the same yaml should be used for multuple types of Kubernetes Cluster like gke, aks, eks, minikube etc.,

To achieve this, I declared a variable in `values.yaml` and used it as   a operand to compare so that, if `cluster_type` is `gke`, my yaml will have one annotation, and if `cluster_type` is `minikube`, it takes another.... below is the sample code

**my sample values.yaml file**

```
global:
# Supported cluster types : gke, minikube
  cluster_type: gke
  name: core-services
  namespace: yeedu
  environment: test
```

**in my service yaml file**

```
{{- if eq "minikube" $.Values.global.cluster_type }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
{{- end }}
```